# Stuck with a Log marker

Tags: android

I am new to Android so only working on Examples to learn and play with things. Currently I am working on an example to Generate Images via Timer Task and I am stuck at a point and I really need an expert advice. Below is the code and where its using Log.i("MARKER", "*********")..... Can some please tell me why I am getting an error in last section of line????

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(“MARKER”,”******************************************”);

        //int numViews = container.getChildCount(); 

        ImageView toAdd = new ImageView(ImagePlayActivity.this);        
        Drawable imgContent = ImagePlayActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        toAdd.setImageDrawable(imgContent);
        toAdd.setTag(“img”+counter++);

        Random rndGen = new Random();

      LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,rndGen.nextInt(300),rndGen.nextInt(300));
        toAdd.setLayoutParams(lp);
        toAdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        container.addView(toAdd);
        //container.invalidate(); 
        toAdd.startAnimation(anim);



    }
};
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like you're using directed double quotes instead of regular double quotes in Log.i(“MARKER”,”******************************************”);

Comment: Show your stack trace error log

Comment: I am only getting an error "Syntax error on token, delete these tokens".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you're using `”` instead of `"`. The Java language does not recognize `”` as a set of quotes to enclose Strings etc. in. Try changing that line to:

```
Log.i("MARKER","******************************************");
```

Comment: Yes that's true but when I do this I get error on ImagePlayActivity and counter++ section. Can you please tell me why is that????? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yup thats done and now error moved to ImagePlayActivity.this and counter++ and it does not show both errors when quotes are not changed.

Comment: ImagePlayActivity cannot be resolved as a type. Thats the error.

Comment: Thats the section which is causing trouble now:
ImageView toAdd = new ImageView(ImagePlayActivity.this);        
        Drawable imgContent = ImagePlayActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        toAdd.setImageDrawable(imgContent);
        toAdd.setTag(“img”+counter++);